# Chart background color on billboard.js

Tags: billboard.js

How do i set the chart background?
I can set the backgroud of the parent, but i only want to set the background to the data space and not axis.

My current solution is to use bb-event-rects class

```
#myChart .bb-event-rects {
  fill-opacity: 1 !important;
  fill: red;
}
```

But it doesn't feel right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that's the easy approach one. If fulfill your needs, that's okay just styling with the css.

But, probably you'll find that `<rect>` elements has blank spaces between.
So, to cover up all the area just add a new `<rect>` element to functioning as styling the background.

Check out the example below:

> **EDIT(03/12/19)**: Implemented new [`background`](https://naver.github.io/billboard.js/release/latest/doc/Options.html#.background) option since `v1.11.0`. Checkout the [Demo](https://naver.github.io/billboard.js/demo/#ChartOptions.Background).
>
> **EDIT**: The simple way:
>
> 1) Just fill the color for event <rect> elements, but in this case you will have blank spaced area in left & right.
>
> ```
> .bb-event-rects .bb-event-rect {
>    fill: cyan;
> }
> ```
>
> 2) Or simply use '[regions](https://naver.github.io/billboard.js/release/latest/doc/Options.html#.regions)' option
>
> ```
> bb.generate({
>    ...
>    regions: [{ axis: "x" }],
> ```
>
> ```
> .bb-region {fill: cyan; }
> ```

```js
var chart = bb.generate({
 data: {
  columns: [
   ["data1", 30, 20, -5, 40, 15, 25],
   ["data2", 3, 10, 20, 10, 25, 15]
  ]
 },
 oninit: function() {
  this.svg.select("g.bb-event-rects").insert("rect")
    .attr("width", "100%")
    .attr("height", "100%")
    .attr("class", "myBgColor");
 }
});
```

```css
.myBgColor {
    fill: cyan;
    fill-opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/billboard.js/dist/billboard.min.css" />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/billboard.js/dist/billboard.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    <title>billboard.js</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="chart"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank's! 
The CSS is solving the issue for now, if i get any troubles with it i will have your solution as a backup plan!